Efficient SQL full data retrieval combining JOINs and WHERE
I have a quite complex data model in my current project's database and I am wondering if there is a better/more efficient way of getting all data, after applying some filters, in a single efficient SQL query. I am using PostgreSQL 15.5, but I assume it could be solved using generic SQL.
For the sake of simplicity, let's simplify the data model so that it would be easier to get to the point.
Given the following tables:
Car                  Engine      Tire         Cars_Tires
-------------------  ----------  -----------  -----------
id, plate, engine    id, model   id, brand    id, car, tire
1, 0001BBC, 1        1, X1       1, B1        1, 1, 1
2, 0002CCN, 2        2, X2       2, B1        2, 1, 3
                                 3, B3        3, 1, 5
                                 4, B2        4, 1, 7
                                 5, B5        5, 2, 2
                                 6, B2        6, 2, 4
                                 7, B7        7, 2, 6
                                 8, B2        8, 2, 8

The goal is to efficiently retrieve all information about all the cars that fulfill the condition "using both brands of tires  and ", obtaining the following JSON, after merging all results for each car:
[
    { "id": 1, "plate": "0001BBC", "engine": 
       { "id": 1, "model": "X1"}, 
       "tires": [{"id": 1, "brand": "B1"}, 
                 {"id": 3, "serial": "B3"}, 
                 {"id": 5, "serial": "B5"}, 
                 {"id": 1, "serial": "B7"}]
    }
]

Notice that there are both a many-to-one and a many-to-many relationships in Car table, with tables Engine and Tire, respectively. They are implemented using a foreign key (i.e., Car.engine) and an auxiliary relation table (i.e., Cars_Tires), respectively.
After considering different alternatives, involving different types of SQL clauses, I have finally settled for a solution with two consecutive SQL queries:
First, obtain the list of all Car ids that fulfill the condition, using:
SELECT 
    "Car".*, "Engine".*, "Tire".* 
FROM   
    "Car" 
LEFT JOIN 
    "Engine" ON "Engine".id = "Car".engine
LEFT OUTER JOIN  
    "Cars_Tires" ON "Cars_Tires".car = "Car".id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    "Tire" ON "Cars_Tires".tire = "Tire".id
WHERE 
    "Tire".brand = 'B1' OR "Tire".brand = 'B3';

-> car_id_list
Second, obtain all data from all Cars whose ids were included in the car_id_list retrieved from the prior query, using:
SELECT 
    "Car".*, "Engine".*, "Tire".* 
FROM 
    "Car" 
LEFT JOIN 
    "Engine" ON "Engine".id = "Car".engine
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    "Cars_Tires" ON "Cars_Tires".car = "Car".id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    "Cars_Tires" ON "Cars_Tires".tire = "Tire".id
WHERE 
    "Car".id = '<car1_id>' {OR "Car".id = '<carN_id>'};

Some very important considerations to be taken into account are:

The first SQL query returns a list of tuples, each one containing information from the row of the JOIN-table obtained after applying all JOIN clauses. Each of these rows contains:
(<Car.id>, <Car.plate>, <Car.engine>, <Engine.id>, <Engine.model>, <Tire.id>, <Tire.brand>)


In order to gather all information of a single Car, it is very likely that multiple of these rows had to be combined, depending on the relationships involved by each Car instance.

Once obtained all JOIN-table rows that fulfill the condition included in the first SQL query, the whole information regarding each car must be retrieved, combining all related rows, before applying the real condition, in order to obtain car_id_list. Notice that the condition involves "using both tires of brands <B1> AND <B3>" but the first SQL query includes it using OR instead of AND. In fact, it is impossible that a single JOIN-table row could match "Tire".brand = 'B1' AND "Tire".brand = 'B3' with a single "Tire".brand value.


RECALL that this is a simplified example. The real data model includes much more tables, fields, and relationships, so as thousands to millions rows for each table. However, each Car will always have a single engine and up to four tires.
So, the question is ... could we do it in a single and efficient SQL query?

There's a lot of prose here. I think it would be helpful to many if you show the desired end result.

In the specific example, do you want all cars that use 1) B1 and/or B3, and others (e,g, B1/B1/B1/B4), 2) B1 and/or B3 only (e,g, B1/B1/B1/B1), 3) Both B1 and B3, and others (e,g, B1/B3/B1/B5), 4) Both B1 and B3 only (e,g, B1/B3/B1/B3)?

@500-InternalServerError Sorry, maybe I should had made it more clear. I tried to give us many details as possible so that it would be clear enough the problem. As said in the post, the goal is achieving the following result: [
{ "id": 1, "plate": "0001BBC", "engine":
{ "id": 1, "model": "X1"},
"tires": [{"id": 1, "brand": "B1"},
{"id": 3, "serial": "B3"},
{"id": 5, "serial": "B5"},
{"id": 1, "serial": "B7"}]
}
]  from the query "Full cars details from all using both tires of brands  and .

@TheImpaler According to the specified content of the tables (as much simplified as possible) the only result that fulfills the condition "Full Car info from all cars using tires of both brands  and  is the car with id = 1, whose Full Car Info is the one showed in the JSON list that is the expected result of the query.

The query shared returns "ERROR:  table name "Cars_Tires" specified more than once" (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/DBvxpkbb), and, please, can you re-read How to ask, because there is too much (non-interesting) info in the question, which makes it hard to find the REAL question.

Assuming the following are true:

all cars have an engine (so we can use an INNER JOIN Car to Engine)
Engine is irrelevant to tire, so we don't need to join on that to find tire brands
All cars have at least 1 tire (so we can INNER JOIN Cars to Cars_Tires)
All tires in Car_Tires exist in Tire (so we can INNER JOIN Car_Tires to Tire),

Then we can find cars which have both B1 and B3 brands of tires:
NOTE: It isn't clear in the question whether you want to output all brands of tire, (including B2, B5, B7 etc) if the car has both B1 and B3 brands of tire present. The code below filters on having B1 and B3, as a starting point, and outputs all brands of tires where at a minimum there is at least 1xB1 and 1xB3 tire present.
There are 2 options:

Find all cars with at least one B1, and all cars with at least one B3, and identify where the car is present in both datasets.
Matching on both brands in the initial query, since both can be present at the same time in a 1:many table relationship.

Option 1:
--get cars with tires of brand B1
WITH b1 AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        car.id
    FROM   
        "Car" AS car
    INNER JOIN
        "Cars_Tires" AS car_tires    
            ON car.id = car_tires.car
    INNER JOIN
        "Tire" AS tire
            ON cars_tires.tire = tire.id
    WHERE 
        tire.brand = 'B1'
),
--get cars with tires of brand B3
b3 AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        car.id
    FROM   
        "Car" AS car
    INNER JOIN
        "Cars_Tires" AS car_tires        
            ON car.id = car_tires.car
    INNER JOIN
        "Tire" AS tire
            ON cars_tires.tire = tire.id
    WHERE 
        tire.brand = 'B3'
),

--now get records that are have both B1 and B3 tires:
bothbrands AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        car_id
    FROM
        b1 
    INNER JOIN
        b3
            ON b1.id = b3.id
)
--get all car details for vehicles with tires in both brands B1 and B3
SELECT 
    car.*,
    engine.id AS engine_id,
    engine.model,
    tire.id AS tire_id,
    tire.brand
FROM
    "Car" AS car
INNER JOIN 
    bothbrands
        ON car.id = bothbrands.id
INNER JOIN
    "Engine" AS engine
        ON car.engine = engine.id
INNER JOIN
    "Car_Tires" AS car_tires
        ON car.id = car_tires.car
INNER JOIN
    "Tire" AS tire
        ON car_tires.tires = tire.id

Since a field cannot exist with the same name more than once, I aliased it to a new name. e.g. engine_id
An alternative to the above would be to match on B1 AND B3, removing the need for additional CTEs:
Option 2:
--get cars with tires of brand B1 and B3
WITH b1b3 AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        car.id
    FROM   
        "Car" AS car
    INNER JOIN
        "Cars_Tires" AS car_tires    
            ON car.id = car_tires.car
    INNER JOIN
        "Tire" AS tire
            ON cars_tires.tire = tire.id
    WHERE 
        tire.brand = 'B1'
    AND tire.brand = 'B3'
)
--get all car details for vehicles with tires in both brands B1 and B3
SELECT 
    car.*,
    engine.id AS engine_id,
    engine.model,
    tire.id AS tire_id,
    tire.brand
FROM
    "Car" AS car
INNER JOIN 
    b1b3
        ON car.id = b1b3.id
INNER JOIN
    "Engine" AS engine
        ON car.engine = engine.id
INNER JOIN
    "Car_Tires" AS car_tires
        ON car.id = car_tires.car
INNER JOIN
    "Tire" AS tire
        ON car_tires.tires = tire.id

